# How does actually "&~" work?

Tags: bash, shell, unix, binary, bit-manipulation

I wonder how does it work in Unix:

```
user$ i=5
user$ echo $((i &~ 1)) 

4
```

what happens inside the parentheses?

Comment: ok, got it

binary 5 is 101
binary 1 is 001 -> ~1 is 110

101 & 110 -> 100 which is 4 in decimals

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok, got it

binary **5** is **101**

binary **1** is **001** -> **~1** is **110**

**101** & **110** -> **100** which is **4** in decimals

Answer (score 4):

Both `&` and `~` are bitwise operators.

- `~1` is unary bitwise negation that produces `-2`
- `5 & -2` is binary bitwise AND operation that produces 4

Comment: [**Read more about Unix Shell operators**](http://www.linuxtopia.org/online_books/advanced_bash_scripting_guide/ops.html)

Comment: `~` is a unary operator, taking one argument.